# Adding text to graph in Perl's GD::Graph?

Tags: perl, graph, charts

I am drawing a graph using [GD::Graph](http://search.cpan.org/dist/GD-Graph) module in Perl.

I can draw the graph fine but in the drawn image I want to add some text around the top of the drawn graph image.  Basically just want to add some text to this drawn image.  However, I don't see an option to do that.

Does someone know if this is doable?

Comment: I have always been stunned at how unprofessional these graphs look.  Have you looked at other options?

Comment: :( this is for an assignment and we have to use this. if you have any suggestions, i'd like to look at them in my pass time

Comment: All the better options (in the R language) don't have the small footprint easy learning curve.  I was hoping you might know :(

Comment: GD::Graph is ugly on the inside, too.  I had to create my own graph type for a project--yuck.  It is mature and powerful, though.  There are some suggestions for other libraries here: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=606732

Comment: You can make the GD::Graphs quite pretty, but the standard ones are very plain.

Answer (score 2):

The following [article](http://linuxgazette.net/issue83/padala.html) outlines methods to include text using GD::Graph. I think if you want to write on the graph itself you may not find anything useful in this article.

Answer (score 2):

Once you have the GD object, you can do anything that GD lets you do, including adding additional text:

```
$gd = $graph->plot( \@data );

$gd->string($font,$x,$y,$string,$color);
```

If you just want to add titles or axes labels, that's already built into GD::Graph.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried title?

From the USAGE section:

```
$graph->set( 
    x_label           => 'X Label',
    y_label           => 'Y label',
    title             => 'Some simple graph',
    y_max_value       => 8,
    y_tick_number     => 8,
    y_label_skip      => 2 
) or die $my_graph->error;
```

**Edit:**

Apparently I misunderstood the question, and the text should be overlayed on the chart area. In that case, the *experimental* get_feature_coordinates method can apparently be used to get "the coordinates of the rectangle within the axes", and from that you should know where you can draw directly on the GD::Image you get from `$graph->plot(\@data)`

Comment: yeah i know abou the title attribute.  However it shows on top of the main graph. I wanted to have a text somewhere between x and y axis

Comment: Ah, so you want the text overlayed on top of the actual chart area? It's probably worth clarifying that in your question.